# extract values from multiple columns using if condition in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have file contains multiple columns. I want to extract values when both col#1 and col#2 are not equal to zero using fortran. I know that this is a very basic doubt I have but I am bit confused in this. I used following idea but not working. It has to remove those line where both col#1 and col#2 are zero and it has to print whereever it will get 1.

Thank you in advance.

```
  if(col1(ii).ne.0.and.col2(ii).ne.0)then
      print*,col1,col2,col3
  end if
```

Input:
 0.00 0.00
 1.00 0.00
 1.00 1.00
 0.00 1.00
 0.00 0.00
 1.00 0.00
 1.00 1.00

Expected output:
 1.00 0.00
 1.00 1.00
 0.00 1.00
 1.00 0.00
 1.00 1.00

Output from code:

1.00 1.00
 1.00 1.00

Comment: I think you need to show us a [mcve]. I can look at those lines and go *yeah, nothing wrong there*, but so what ?

Comment: It is not printing line as per expected output. It is only printing lines, where both col#1 and col#2 are equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your logic is flawed. If I understand you correctly; you want to remove lines where either col#1 OR col#2 are not zero. Try this:-

if(col1(ii) .NE. 0 .OR. col2(ii) .NE. 0)then
      print*,col1,col2
  end if

Alternatively (same output):

if(.NOT. (col1(ii) .EQ. 0 .AND. col2(ii) .EQ. 0) )then
      print*,col1,col2
  end if

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can mark it as the accepted answer, so it will be easier for other peaple with the same problem to find a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The logic has a flaw and you are missing the index in the print statement:

```
  if(col1(ii).ne.0.or.col2(ii).ne.0)then
      print*,col1(ii),col2(ii),col3(ii)
  end if
```

provided that you have a loop around the total.

Also have a look at statements line `where` and `any`